# jquery how to make an element comeback to initial position after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using jQuery to make some animations in my website but i'm just copying some portions of code and i haven't really got any skills in jQuery.
My problem is that i have a button that makes my animation start on click and the animated block moves but i want him to go back at the end of the animation to his initial place to make impossible to get the animated block so far by clickinG much times on the button.
I hope it's clear, here is my code :

HTML

```
<div id="button">Click here</div>
<div id="square"></div>
```

CSS

```
#square { width:100px; height:100px; position:relative;}
```

JavaScript

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
$( "#square" ).animate({
left: "-=60px",
}, 400);
});
```

How can i get the quare coming back to his initial position after the animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a complete callback function to readjust the position of the element. See: http://codepen.io/TheStonedTurtle/pen/gLRevN

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$( "#square" ).animate({
  left: "-60px",
}, 400, function(){
  $( "#square" ).css('left','0px');
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is simple, useful, and really helping me ! That's exactly what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jquery animate, you could create an animation in css and trigger that animation with the addition of a class.By default css animations return to their initial state, see example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems really interesting but the only way i found out to trigger my animation using only html/css was with an :active and it wasn't really usefull because i want to create many animations with only one button evenement and using this is limiting me to one animated div only.

Answer (score 0):

For smoother animation I will suggest use combination of js and css.

Example Snippet:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#square").addClass("animate").delay(400).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).removeClass("animate");
    next();
  });
});
```

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform .4s linear;
}
#square.animate {
  transform: translate3d(-60px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Click here</div>
<div id="square"></div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795871/jquery-how-to-make-an-element-comeback-to-initial-position-after-animation/40795957#
```